# How to display a model in Swagger-UI that isn't used as an endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, model, swagger-ui

I created a simple API spring boot just with 1 entity, controller and repository, configured swagger-ui then is everything working as expected, then I create just a new entity, and this isn't displayed in swagger-ui. Is there any way to add this to swagger?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Address")
    public class Address {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "emp_id")
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
    
        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;
    
        @Column(name = "email_id")
        private String emailId;
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
...
```

I would like to add this new entity to Models without a controller.